# Change the keyboard in UITextField with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield, iphone-softkeyboard

I have a table with several textFields in several cells, each with different input keyboards (numeric for phone number, standard for name, etc.).

When I change the editing text field by selecting one when other is editing, I want the first text field to hide the keyboard (the one which is being used) and only then the new keyboard to appear.

But putting [textField resignFirstResponder] doesn't solve my problem (the new one appears without the other disappearing, making the animation unnoticeable).

I tried to put the thread sleeping, but it didn't work as I wished.

Is there a way to have this animation?

Thanks a lot.